# uniform highp mat4 not populated with values

Tags: ios, opengl-es, glsl

I am passing a view-projection matrix into my OpenGLSL 2.0 shaders.

In my fragment shader, the corresponding matrix is literally being set with no values. I have checked and n-checked that the programs and uniforms are being linked and set appropriately--no issues.

What am I missing???

**Obj-C Code:**

```
//Calculates the required matrices
    GLKMatrix4 cameraViewProjectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4Multiply(self->_projectionMatrix_CameraView, self->_cameraViewMatrix);
    GLKMatrix4 iCameraViewProjectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4Invert(cameraViewProjectionMatrix, NULL);

    GLKMatrix4 lightSourceCameraViewProjectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4Multiply(self->_projectionMatrix_LightSource, self->_lightSourceCameraViewMatrix);
    GLKMatrix4 shadowMapBiasMatrix = GLKMatrix4Make(0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                                                        0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                                                        0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f,
                                                        0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
    GLKMatrix4 cameraViewProjectionToShadowMapMatrix = GLKMatrix4Multiply(shadowMapBiasMatrix, lightSourceCameraViewProjectionMatrix);

//This confirms the values are bound and exist in the matrices
    NSLog(@"UNIFORM_I_CAMERAVIEW_PROJECTION_MATRIX: %d", compositeSceneTexturesShaderUniforms[UNIFORM_I_CAMERAVIEW_PROJECTION_MATRIX]);
    NSLog(@"UNIFORM_WORLD_TO_SHADOW_MAP_MATRIX: %d", compositeSceneTexturesShaderUniforms[UNIFORM_WORLD_TO_SHADOW_MAP_MATRIX]);

    NSLog(@"\n[%f, %f, %f, %f],\n[%f, %f, %f, %f],\n[%f, %f, %f, %f],\n[%f, %f, %f, %f]",
        iCameraViewProjectionMatrix.m00, iCameraViewProjectionMatrix.m01, iCameraViewProjectionMatrix.m02, iCameraViewProjectionMatrix.m03,
        iCameraViewProjectionMatrix.m10, iCameraViewProjectionMatrix.m11, iCameraViewProjectionMatrix.m02, iCameraViewProjectionMatrix.m13,
        iCameraViewProjectionMatrix.m20, iCameraViewProjectionMatrix.m21, iCameraViewProjectionMatrix.m02, iCameraViewProjectionMatrix.m23,
        iCameraViewProjectionMatrix.m30, iCameraViewProjectionMatrix.m31, iCameraViewProjectionMatrix.m02, iCameraViewProjectionMatrix.m33);

    NSLog(@"\n[%f, %f, %f, %f],\n[%f, %f, %f, %f],\n[%f, %f, %f, %f],\n[%f, %f, %f, %f]",
        cameraViewProjectionToShadowMapMatrix.m00, cameraViewProjectionToShadowMapMatrix.m01, cameraViewProjectionToShadowMapMatrix.m02, cameraViewProjectionToShadowMapMatrix.m03,
        cameraViewProjectionToShadowMapMatrix.m10, cameraViewProjectionToShadowMapMatrix.m11, cameraViewProjectionToShadowMapMatrix.m02, cameraViewProjectionToShadowMapMatrix.m13,
        cameraViewProjectionToShadowMapMatrix.m20, cameraViewProjectionToShadowMapMatrix.m21, cameraViewProjectionToShadowMapMatrix.m02, cameraViewProjectionToShadowMapMatrix.m23,
        cameraViewProjectionToShadowMapMatrix.m30, cameraViewProjectionToShadowMapMatrix.m31, cameraViewProjectionToShadowMapMatrix.m02, cameraViewProjectionToShadowMapMatrix.m33);

//Binds the matrices
    glUniformMatrix3fv(compositeSceneTexturesShaderUniforms[UNIFORM_I_CAMERAVIEW_PROJECTION_MATRIX], 1, 0, iCameraViewProjectionMatrix.m);
    glUniformMatrix3fv(compositeSceneTexturesShaderUniforms[UNIFORM_WORLD_TO_SHADOW_MAP_MATRIX], 1, 0, cameraViewProjectionToShadowMapMatrix.m);
```

**Fragment Shader Code:**

```
uniform highp mat4 iCameraViewProjectionMatrix;
uniform highp mat4 worldToShadowMapMatrix;

void main(void){

//There is real code, but I am just testing if values are being passed in
//because everything else works until I attempt to transform using these
//matrices and they just output ZEROS!!!
    gl_FragColor = vec4(abs(worldToShadowMapMatrix[0][0]));
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

All I want to do is convert screen coordinates to world coordinates and play with those values to mess with a shadow map...

Comment: Have you called `glUseProgram` before setting the uniforms?

Comment: Yes, and I am fully able to render to the screen with literally anything else. Even setting gl_FragCoord = vec4(1.0, abs(worldToShadowMapMatrix[0][0]), 0.0, 1.0) would produce a red output. This code is from a compositing shader as a final pass. My inputs to other texture buffers work perfectly as well, and I can display them through this shader when I pass through their texture values.

Everything appears to be set up correctly... it's just not receiving the values from these matrices...?

Comment: I am also successfully passing all my other uniforms.

Answer (score 0):

Typo of stupid proportions considering the amount of time spent troubleshooting:

**Mistake:**
    glUniformMatrix3fv

**Fix:**
    glUniformMatrix4fv